how to play a wav file in mono mode with python-vlc?
I know how to play a wav file with python_vlc,
e.g (here to play an audio stream)
import vlc

instance=vlc.Instance('--input-repeat=-1','--fullscreen')
player=instance.media_player_new()
url="my url"
media=instance.media_new(url)
player.set_media(media)
player.play()


but I didn't find any command to play it in mono mode.
Any help appreciated.
I've asked the support of my hardware and searched among stackoverflow questions.

it seems the solution was in alsamixer:
type alsamixer
select the 'DAC' tab
switch it from stereo to mono.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

the solution is very clear, just follow the instruction and it will work
